# Lenovo ThinkPad T480s Won't Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, lenovo-laptop

My laptop won't hibernate. The screen goes black but the lights on the keyboard and the back of the lid stay on. After a few seconds clicking or pressing the space bar brings the login screen up. If I leave it without pressing anything the battery eventually dies. I checked all the power settings and everything is correct. Any ideas what could cause this?

Edit: Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Edit 2: Flashed to the latest BIOS with no luck. Here is the system event log when I hibernate it:

**Source - Level - Message**

Kernel-Power - Information - User-mode process attempted to change the system state by calling SetSuspendState or SetSystemPowerState APIs.

volmgr - Error - The system could not successfully load the crash dump driver.

Time-Service - Warning - NtpClient was unable to set a domain peer to use as a time source because of discovery error. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval thereafter. The error was: The entry is not found (0x800706E1)

Time-Service - Information - The time provider 'VMICTimeProvider' has indicated that the current hardware and operating environment is not supported and has stopped. This behavior is expected for VMICTimeProvider on non-HyperV-guest environments. This may be the expected behavior for the current provider in the current operating environment as well.

Comment: Please state the operating system used and its version number. Users ask questions about many different OS here, and the correct solution will vary based on the OS. To answer, please click [edit] and put your necessary information in your question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Assuming Windows. `powercfg -h on`. Reboot. Try again.

Comment: @shawn It is Windows. Ran that command but same issue. Flashed BIOS to the latest version as well.

Comment: Check the BIOS for power and sleep options. Make sure that S3 and/or S4 is enabled and that WiFi booting is not.